# How to show the combined effect of two covariates in a simple regression?

Tags: multiple-regression, interaction, econometrics, predictor

Say I want to build a simple model, and I have four variables available to me:

Age, gender ($D_1$, 1 is female, 0 male), income, and whether the person is Hispanic or not ($D_2$, 1 is Hispanic, 0 otherwise).

If I want to test the effect (doesn't matter on what) of only Hispanic females (holding age and income constant), would the model look something like the one below?

$y = \beta_0 + \beta_1D_1D_2 + \beta_2Age + \beta_3Income$

or am I totally off?

Then, to look at the effect of just females in general; could I extrapolate that from that same model, or would I have to look at a completely different one?

Comment: What do you mean by "test the effect of only Hispanic females"? If you're restricting analysis to Hispanic females, why would $D_1$ and $D_2$ enter the model (when their values are fixed at 1)? I'm not sure I understand precisely what procedure you're proposing to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly you just need to use the interaction terms in the right way. The model you are after would be
$$y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 D_{1i} + \beta_2 D_{2i} + \beta_3 D_{1i}D_{2i} + \beta_4 \text{Age}_i + \beta_5 \text{Income}_i + \epsilon_i$$

In order to get the different group effects you just need to "switch on" the different dummies for gender and hispanic. Here are the versions of the above model for given values of $D_{1i}$ and $D_{2i}$.

For male, non-hispanic,

$y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_4 \text{Age}_i + \beta_5 \text{Income}_i + \epsilon_i$

For male, hispanic,

$y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_2 D_{2i} + \beta_4 \text{Age}_i + \beta_5 \text{Income}_i + \epsilon_i$

For female, non-hispanic,

$y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 D_{1i} + \beta_4 \text{Age}_i + \beta_5 \text{Income}_i + \epsilon_i$

For female, hispanic,

$y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 D_{1i} + \beta_2 D_{2i} + \beta_3 D_{1i}D_{2i} + \beta_4 \text{Age}_i + \beta_5 \text{Income}_i + \epsilon_i$

This should illustrate how the model works for the four different groups. In order to get the partial effect of being female take the derivative of the model with respect to $D_{1i}$, which is
$$\frac{\partial y_i}{\partial D_{1i}} = \beta_1 + \beta_3 D_{2i}$$

So to get the effect of being female and hispanic on the outcome (relative to non-hispanic males) you add $\beta_1$ and $\beta_3$. To get the effect of being female and not hispanic, switch off the $D_{2i}$ dummy by setting it to zero, so the partial effect is only $\beta_1$.